# Jarvis March Algo not working. condition always false

Tags: java

using this link, i saw an algo about the gift wrapping algorithm / jarvis march 
https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall14/cps130/notes/scribe14.pdf

i tried coding it but it doesnt follow the algo.
here is my main function

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class driver {
    static Point[] points;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random rand = new Random();
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.println("Jarvis Algorithm Test\n");
        boolean i = true;

       while(i){
           System.out.println("SELECT:");
           System.out.println("RANDOM:");
           System.out.println("USER INPUT:");
           System.out.print(":");
         //  String comm = scan.nextLine();
          String comm = "random";
           comm = comm.toLowerCase();



          if(comm.equals("random")){
                randomize();
                i = false;
                 }
             else if(comm.equals("user input")){
                userinput();
             }
             else{
                System.out.println("INVALID");
             }
         System.out.println("");
       }

        Jarvis j = new Jarvis(); 
        j.convexHull(points);   


    }

    public static void randomize(){

    int p = 10; //= askpoints();
        points = new Point[p];
        for(int i = 0; i<p; i++){
              points[i] = new Point();
              points[i].x = rand.nextInt(300) + 20  ;
              points[i].y = rand.nextInt(300) + 20 ;
              System.out.println(points[i].x+ " " +points[i].y);

        }
    }

    public static void userinput(){
        int n = askpoints();
        points = new Point[n];
        System.out.println("Enter "+ n +" x, y cordinates");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new Point();
            points[i].x = scan.nextInt();
            points[i].y = scan.nextInt();
        }        
    }

    public static int askpoints(){
        System.out.print("how many points:");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        return i;
    }




}
```

here is my jarvis code 
/**
 ** Java Program to Implement Jarvis Algorithm
 * http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-to-implement-jarvis-algorithm/
 **/

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/** Class point **/
class Point
{
    int x, y;
}

/** Class Jarvis **/
public class Jarvis extends JFrame{    
    public ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    private boolean CCW(Point p, Point q, Point r)
    {
 //     int val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);

     //    if (val >= 0)
   //          return false;
    //  return true;
        return (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - p.x) < (r.y - p.y) * (q.y - p.x);
    }

    public void convexHull(Point[] points){
        int n = points.length;

        int[] next = new int[n];
        int[] prev = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(next, -1);
        int l = 0;
        for(int i =1; i<n;i++){
            if(points[i].x < points[l].x){
                l = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(points[l].x);

        int p = l;
        int q;
        do{
                q = p + 1;
                    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
                        System.out.println(CCW(points[p],points[i],points[q]));
                        if( p!=i &&CCW(points[p],points[i],points[q])){

                            q = i;

                        }

                        next[p] = q;
                        prev[q] = p;
                        p = q;
                    }
        }while(p == l);






    }
    /*
     *   display(points, next);

    */


}
```

i tried to print the values of next to know the indexes however the values are all 0. so i tried printing what CCW returns and it always returns false. why is that i followed the algorithm in the link.

any tips?